# Disable modules in owasp dependency-check maven plugin

Tags: owasp, maven-dependency-check-plugin

In my project I use `dependency-check-maven` to run OWASP verifications. Project contains several java modules and a front end module. Configuration in `pom` is basic one like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <failBuildOnCVSS>4</failBuildOnCVSS>
        <suppressionFiles>
            <suppressionFile>owasp-suppressions.xml</suppressionFile>
        </suppressionFiles>
        <cveUrlBase>...</cveUrlBase>
        <cveUrlModified>...</cveUrlModified>
        <format>ALL</format>
        <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
        <cveValidForHours>24</cveValidForHours>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to configure the plugin such way that it ignores my front end module but analyses all other ones?

I try to run `mvn -Dowasp.dependency-check.excludes=frontend-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:aggregate` in the root folder of my project  but verification is done in `frontend` as well

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to each submodule to be excluded:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Won't this ignore all owasp.org checks?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Yes. But only in the module (and its children) where it is defined. Add this snippet only to the front-end modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue to ignore some javascript modules to be analyzed by the dependency check.

As you can see at https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/1009 the developers have an open PR to resolve this request.

I've solved this by not building the javascript module:

```
mvn verify -pl '!frontend'
```

It's just a workaround to get the results of the dependency-check locally.

Maybe there exists better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much (or any) documentation about this, but it can be achieved through Maven configuration by adding an exclusion

The format of the exclusion is `<exlude>groupId:artefact</exclude>` and the following example illustrates how to do it for your case but bear in mind that I don't know your groupId so I used **com.example** instead

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Your configuration -->
        <excludes>
          <exclude>com.example:frontend</exclude>
        </excludes>  
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There are some other use cases in this Github issue: https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/1009